# How to blit a background without erasing other layers

Tags: pygame, python-2.6

I have 2 layers in Pygame right now:
1st: Background image that moves
2nd: the characters, items, lasers, etc. this layer is obviously in front of the 1st layer.

however, whenever i try to blit the 1st layer (background), it erases anything (particularly the lasers and any other items that appears only for a certain amount of time) that is on the 2nd layer. Is there a way so that even if the background blits, it doesnt erase all the contents of layer 2?

Comment: In short, no.  What you are currently doing with having the background and the other items on different surfaces is good, and will simplify your problem.  All you have to do is blit the front on every time you blit the background on.  There really is no other way to  do this.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit , there are some optimizations discussed here which are useful, specifically dirty rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

in youre loop you need to do something like this

```
while True:
    screen.blit(background(0,0))
    screen.blit(item(100,100))
    #etc.
```

this way the loop while blit the background then blit the image then re-blit the background to refresh the images on top then re-blit the images on top

this way it will blit eachlayer over and over again refreshing on each iteration if the loop i could help more if you showed some of youre code